# Cassandra's Python CQLEngine model inheritance

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

I have the following object model:

```
class Data(Model):
  __keyspace__ = 'varilog'
  __table_name__ = 'md_data'
  id = columns.TimeUUID(partition_key=True, primary_key=True, required=True)
  device = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
  property = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
  field = columns.Text(primary_key=True, required=True)
  cyclestamp = columns.DateTime(static=True)
  type = columns.Text(discriminator_column=True)
  #text_value = columns.Text() # Will work
  #value = columns.Text(db_field='text_value') # Will work but...

class DataText(Data):
  __discriminator_value__ = 'str'
  value = columns.Text(db_field='text_value') # Always None
  #text_value = columns.Text() # Ok also
```

When I query an object, depending on the value of the `type` column, the correct object is returned (`DataText` in this example), however it's `value` is `None` while if I uncomment `text_value` I'll have the correct value.

It looks like `db_field` is not supported in a child class. Is this a bug?

Comment: You're better off filing a JIRA for bugs https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/PYTHON/issues/PYTHON-110?filter=allopenissues

Comment: What version were you using? This works fine on master.